# Does the Osprey ramp have several configurations?

Tags: v-22

I am building a model of the Osprey.  The kit gives me an option to stow the ramp or cut the ramp in half into two units, the first section lowered and the tail section swing into the top of the aircraft as shown in any photos I have seen.  In those internet photos the ramp is not user friendly for anything on wheels like a fork lift.  My question is does the ramp swing down as one unit providing a beveled leading edge and a less of an incline for wheeled equipment?  I have not seen anything that suggest this except the piece to this model kit.  The end of it is tapered to lie flat on the tarmac.  Even the guys at the museum couldn’t answer this. If so, I plan on modifying the kit to do all configurations.[image: model kit ramp part notice tapered tarmac edge]

Answer (score 7):

> Does the Osprey ramp have several configurations?

**Yes.**

> Does the ramp swing down as one unit providing a beveled leading edge and a less of an incline for wheeled equipment?

**No.**  (Not *one unit* as depicted by the plastic part in the photo...)

The part shown in your photo is actually two parts:

The Osprey, (like the C-130) rear opening consists of a lower "ramp", that is hinged at the rear of the cargo deck and opens downwards and outwards to be level with the deck, or it may be lowered to the ground.  There is also an upper rear "door" that is hinged up by the tail, and is raised upwards and inwards to provide clearance for cargo being loaded via the ramp.

You can see them clearly in the photo here:  [V-22 Osprey loading](https://secure.boeingimages.com/archive/Boeing-Phantom-Badger-Drives-Aboard-V-22-Osprey--2013-2JRSXLJLXPGE.html)

These two parts are not joined, but can be raised and lowered independently resulting in several different possible configurations.

The model company likely molded them as a single piece for ease of manufacture, as well as ease of assembly for builders who wish to build the model with the rear end closed.  Therefore, to accurately depict what they look like when open on the actual aircraft, the plastic parts would need to be separated.

There is no practical way to join the two pieces and open them as a single unit.  As you can see from the photo, additional ramp extensions are needed for tires to roll from ground level onto the main ramp for smooth loading.

Comment: Extensions, of course.  I couldn’t see how it could had been done the way I suggested.  Great answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple images online, showing a 2 part rear hatch. The rearmost part folds up, the rest folds down.

This, from Military.com
[image]

https://www.military.com/equipment/mv-22-osprey

The only image I saw of a one piece ramp was another model.

Comment: The C-130 has a similar ramp & door. The door can be either up (stowed, as in the photo), or down. The ramp can be either up (which, with the door down, makes for a sealed back end of the aircraft), or level (as in the photo) or down on the ground (ie lower than level, allowing for easy entry of foot traffic or small wheeled vehicles - or not so small in the case of the mighty Herk).

Comment: I love that plane.  The ramp is a smooth transition into the cargo bay so that’s what I was looking for in the Osprey. The Osprey, I guess, was designed as a troop carrier and learning of the ramp extensions for the occasional need or using a forklift to the leveled ramp configuration makes much more sense to me.  Thanks guys.

Comment: I wish the view from my job was that good.

Comment: @Schwern The view comes with the possibility of being shot at.

Comment: @Zac67 So does every job in America these days. 